# eval backward print __dict__ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, eval

Why can't I use `eval` against `__dict__` option, e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> s = str( os.__dict__ )
>>> d = eval( s )
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Everywhere it is commonly used to cast str() over dict or list, and eval backward. What is it here?

Comment: Why? `os` is a builtin, so you'll get the same thing every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the string you're trying to `eval`, you'll see that it contains things like

```
>>> str(os.getpid)
'<built-in function getpid>'
```

which are not valid Python expressions, so they can't be `eval`'d.

Using `eval` in this way is not "common everywhere". In fact the use of `eval` is almost universally a code smell.

Comment: What should I do? I'm trying to dump `self.__dict__` of class, for debug.

Comment: @Watch0nMe use `pickle`.

Comment: There is such: `TypeError: can't pickle Connection object`. That is why I'm trying to find universal solution. Looks like dict and eval - such common...

Comment: It's not a universal solution -- there is no universal solution. And as I said, `eval` is not a common solution either. It's strongly discouraged.

Comment: just imagine how it is comfortably for developer ( may be only for debug mode ) to have such option, to dump anything to string and recovery backward.

Comment: "**eval is evil**" (true for 99,99% of the code where _eval_ is used)

Comment: @Watch0nMe Regardless of how useful it would be, it's not possible. You cannot store a network connection, for example, and in general you'd have to dump the full state of the world. That seems to be the very problem you're facing.

Comment: I've forced this with loop over `self.__dict__` and `type( key )`, if it is `str` or `dict` or `list` or `set` or `int` or `float`, it will be dumped, otherwise - skipped. Thank you.